# how to receive email (especially from Microsoft Outlook!) on a Ubuntu server with a dynamic IP address?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email

I have a Ubuntu server that receives email for several domains via postfix.  There's some DNS magic to update the domains' IP addresses whenever the server's address changes, which is infrequent.

I can receive email from various email services, definitely including Gmail, just fine.

But I cannot receive email from some (all?) Microsoft/Outlook email services.  When I attempt to send a test email from an outlook.com account the email bounces after a day or two with this message:

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> Your message couldn't be delivered. Despite repeated attempts to deliver your message, querying the Domain Name System (DNS) for the recipient's domain location information failed.
>
> For more information and tips to fix this issue see this article: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389361.

I *think* email from Microsoft/Outlook stopped working when the server was changed from a static ip address to a dynamic ip address.  I'm not certain, and while I would prefer a static ip address, my ISP does not offer one.

So, basically three questions:

[1] What's going on?  (Is there some sort of anti-dynamic IP address filtering by Microsoft/Outlook?)

[2] How to fix whatever Microsoft/Outlook doesn't like?

[3] What service (email forwarding?) might work around the problem inexpensively?

My server supports several very low traffic domains, so I would prefer to avoid any solution that has a per-domain cost.

If you're curious to see the problem in action, try emailing stack-exchange-question-March-28-2024@suicidesquid.com from an outlook.com account.  It may take a few days for email to bounce, but eventually you should get the error message I quoted above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your domain's MX target `mail.damnlies.com` is a CNAME alias. This is not allowed by the DNS specification (see RFC 2181 section 10.3) and mail servers are allowed to refuse to follow CNAMEs in MX on those grounds.

But even if they follow the CNAME regardless, the authoritative DNS servers for your actual MX name (i.e. for `damnlies.com` which is the target of the CNAME) are returning a `SERVFAIL` DNS error when queried for AAAA records (i.e. IPv6 addresses).

```
C:\> nslookup -q=AAAA damnlies.com. ns-98-a.gandi.net
$ host -t AAAA damnlies.com. ns-33-b.gandi.net
$ dig damnlies.com. AAAA @ns-100-c.gandi.net
```

SERVFAIL is the completely wrong answer to give, even if you indeed don't have any IPv6 addresses – instead of "No records of such type" it really indicates "Complete failure to handle the query", and if the mail server gets this error during the AAAA query, it would be entirely reasonable for it to abort the operation entirely and not continue with the A (IPv4) query.

(There is no error code for "No records of such type". The expected result, if the name has no IPv6 addresses but does have some other record types, would be a *successful* answer with 0 records, as e.g. you can try with `dig -t aaaa ipv4only.arpa`.)

> [3] What service (email forwarding?) might work around the problem inexpensively?

Correct DNS configuration should work around the problem for free – although I can't say why Gandi servers are returning a failure, but that's also something they ought to be fixing for free if it's a fault on their side.

There are many hosting companies that would let you spin up an inexpensive VPS for running Postfix, which could accept mail for your domains via SMTP and relay them to your main server (also via SMTP – or maybe via UUCP if you prefer), *or* could let your home server "borrow" the VPS's external IP address through a VPN (less reliable), although either way you'll usually have to ask the provider nicely for SMTP network restrictions to be lifted.

Comment: Wow!  What a clear, thorough answer!  I've contacted Gandi about the DNS issue.  It's possible I've somehow misconfigured the domain's DNS, but I've never configured it with ipv6 at all, so either something got defaulted incorrectly at some point or the error is Gandi's.  I'm going to cross my fingers about the CNAME issue and hope that's not a problem once the ipv6 issue is resolved.  My mistake to assume that CNAME could be used that way, but it's key to my automatic migration when the dynamic IP address changes.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Please email me at u1686_gravity@suicidesquid.com so I can buy you a beer (or the beverage of your choice).

Comment: I really don't see how it helps with dynamic IP here. You would get the exact same address-updating functionality if your MX was pointing directly to the CNAME target (i.e. make it `MX damnlies.com`, as opposed to `MX mail.damnlies.com`) – after all you're updating the A target address, not the CNAME target, so it is still a level of indirection either way.

Comment: Fair point.  I haven't touched those files in at least a year.  My intent, as I recall, was to be able to update my mail server's IP address without changing my webserver's IP address.  I should probably change it as you say, certainly if the email problem persists once the ipv6 issue resolves.